# How to work around a high seatpost?

Tags: bike-fit, seatpost, adjustment, ergonomics

So I bought this old bike but realized that its seatpost is stuck and high. When I ride I feel uncomfortable because it's slightly too high for me. Also I realized that it's really difficult to fix the stuck seatpost. Is there a trick that could help me work around this problem and make me feel comfortable when riding the bike?

Comment: There's a good chance your local mechanic will be better equipped to unstuck it.

Comment: There is no work-around, you'll just have to get it unstuck somehow.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove a stuck seatpost?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/29632/how-to-remove-a-stuck-seatpost)

Comment: If it's only very slightly too high, then it _might_ be possible to swap the saddle for one that is slightly lower when mounted on the same post. If it's an old style clamp mount (http://sheldonbrown.com/harris/images/ST4200.jpg), you _might_ be able to mount a saddle (not necessarily the current one) with the rails clamped at the bottom rather than the top. But getting it unstuck is the real answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sheldon Brown has a thorough article about stuck seat posts. http://sheldonbrown.com/stuck-seatposts.html

Thick soled shoes might also work, if the saddle isn't that much too high.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a steel frame some people recommend heating up the seat tube (LIGHTLY) to expand the metal and then try and wiggle the post out but that seemed like too much effort to me.

When I got a seatpost stuck in a frame I went to an auto garage and put the frame in a vice. Then used their pneumatic air chisel on the seatpost and it came flying out in seconds.

If you go down that route, it might be an idea to give some money/beers to garage as a thank you for using their kit.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker so I couldn't fully understood your way. So I understood that a vice is this thing https://www.machinemart.co.uk/images/library/product/huge/04/040314105.jpg so you put the frame in it so it doesn't move. Then what did you use to take the seatpost? Can you explain this 'pneumatic air chisel' thingy please?!

Comment: 'pneumatic air chisel' seems to be for screws ... so I can't understand how you used it to get the seatpost out! http://www.northerntool.com/images/product/features/154130.jpg

Comment: chisels are not used for screws. The air chisel hammers the chisel head back and forth onto the seatpost with lots of power forcing it out with more power than can be achieved by hand.

Comment: Air Hammer Chisel - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aF8JObMwUQ