# How do I unstuck this seat post? Materials unknown

Tags: seatpost, stuck

I have a road bike and the seat post needs some height adjustments but for the love of me I can't get it unstuck.

I have tried heating it a bit, I have tried bending it open as well as adding some lubricant. I am twisting at the seat to get it unstuck first before trying to move it up and down.

Some images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This looks like aluminium alloys that bonded together due to oxidation. Or it might be aluminium and steel. I do not think you can do much more than what you did besides trying more force and more heat. You may try to clamp something much longer to the seat or the seatpost to get more leverage.

Comment: Soak it in penetrating oil. Both from the top and the bottom (might have to remove the cranks, unless you are able to spray through a bottle cage mounting hole). The frame almost looks like carbon (hard to tell from the photos), which would mean you have to be careful with heat.

Comment: If all else fails, the last resort is usually to cut off the seatpost and then use a hacksaw blade to make a long cut and try to get it out that way.

Comment: @Michael that's exactly what I once had to do. I didn't cut off the seatpost though, so I could still grab it with some locking pliers after I was done sawing. **Warning**: the seatpost gets hot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove a stuck seatpost?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/29632/how-to-remove-a-stuck-seatpost)

Comment: I DO NOT KNOW if this is carbon fibre safe, but among the best of penetrating oils is 50/50 Acetone and ATF (auto transmission fluid) mixture.  || Also very good - but  friend expressed concern for the possibility of salicylate poisoning is 50/50 ATF and methyl salicylate (aka Oil of wintergreen)(Aspirin on steroid).

Answer (score 8):

I'd consider the seatpost scrap and expect to replace it.

Flip the bike frame and clamp the seatpost firmly in a bench-mounted vise.

Use the leverage offered by the length of frame to rotate the frame around the seatpost while applying upward pressure.  You can do this alone but a person at each end of the bike can be easier.

Leaving the rear wheel on can also give more leverage and also protects the stays from bending forces.

Try to "listen with your fingers" and if it feels wrong then stop and re-evaluate.

Answer (score 7):

There are professional services available that can remove the post in this situation and save the frame. As you have a carbon frame this is financially viable.

The system is usually based on pulling the post straight up under hydraulic pressure but other methods exist: though may be trade secret.

Your aluminium seatpost has corroded and expanded (perhaps due to damp environment or salty water/sweat). Heat will not help and will make your job harder. Extreme cold may help eg commercially available spray freeze products like finishline chillzone etc. But if the corrosion/expasion is as bad as it looks, it still might not be the solution and back to my first suggestion.

Don't cut off the seatpost.

further reading:

https://www.bikeradar.com/news/stuck-seatpost-removal/

https://theseatpostman.com/

Comment: If I may, apropos other people's mention of penetrating oil: "penetrating oil" really is special stuff, and it doesn't just mean reaching for a can of WD-40 (which was originally formulated for something completely different). Also the issue with penetrating oil and "carbon" frames is not the carbon fibre in itself but the resin holding it together (i.e. carbon+resin=composite).

Answer (score 5):

The frame is carbon and the post appears to be aluminum.

Don't use heat, and hopefully the heat already applied was far away from the frame. It's too easy for this to go wrong with carbon, which is not tolerant of applied heat.

The idea of "carbon-safe" products always being necessary when working with carbon can be overstated, but in this case you probably could find a penetrating oil product where the solvent component is capable of damaging resin. It's probably a good idea to use a penetrating oil marketed as safe for composites.

Soak it in and let it sit a while (possibly days with multiple applications). Getting some worked in from the bottom either through the seat tube cage bolt holes or the BB shell can also help. Then, if twisting by the seat doesn't work, go after it with a pipe wrench or clamp the post in a vise to get more leverage.

Comment: I've wondered in the past about drilling a hole across the seat post to put a T bar through. Studding would be good. Then you could twist with serious torque with no risk of slipping, and simultaneously pull

Comment: Thanks. I realised that the frame is carbon but wasnt sure if the Tube holding it was carbon as well. The heat was decently far away, I don't think I damaged anything. I will accept an answer if I managed to somehow unstuck the seatpost using one of the methods

Comment: @NathanKnutson In the second image (with the hand with clearly visible fingers) there is what looks like a compression slot in the seat tube - I've not seen these on carbon frames before (but I have a lot more experience with steel!) - I thought that would make it easier to compress the seat tube, which (IIRC) isn't great for carbon - are these common?

Answer (score 1):

Try an oscillating saw with a very dull blade to **vibrate** it off.    Combine with penetrating oil that is safe for this.